# wxpython textctrl line and column

Tags: python, wxpython, line, textctrl

I am writing a text editor using wxpython. I want to display the line & column numbers based on the position of the text pointer(when changed using keyboard or mouse), in the statusbar.

I tried to do it using the below code:

```
import wx

class TextFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Text Editor', size=(300, 250))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1) 

        self.multiText = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1,"",size=(200, 100), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.EXPAND)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(self.multiText, proportion=1, flag=wx.CENTER|wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.CreateStatusBar()

        self.multiText.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.updateLineCol)
        self.multiText.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.updateLineCol)

    def updateLineCol(self, event):
        #lineNum = len(self.multiText.GetRange( 0, self.multiText.GetInsertionPoint() ).split("\n"))
        l,c = self.multiText.PositionToXY(self.multiText.GetInsertionPoint())

        self.StatusBar.SetStatusText(str(l)+","+str(c), number=0)

        event.Skip()

app = wx.App(False)
frame = TextFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

I tried the below 2 ways to achieve that:

```
1.) lineNum = len(self.multiText.GetRange( 0, self.multiText.GetInsertionPoint() ).split("\n"))
2.) l,c = self.multiText.PositionToXY(self.multiText.GetInsertionPoint())
```

But, both, always give the line & column values of previous position of the pointer instead of current.

Is there a way to display the current line & column values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to bind to EVT_KEY_UP instead of EVT_KEY_DOWN. That way the event handler isn't called until after you have finished typing. I also updated the content written to the statusbar to make it a bit clearer which value was which:

```
import wx

class TextFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, 'Text Editor', size=(300, 250))

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1) 

        self.multiText = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1,"",size=(200, 100), style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.EXPAND)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        sizer.Add(self.multiText, proportion=1, flag=wx.CENTER|wx.EXPAND)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.CreateStatusBar()

        self.multiText.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP, self.updateLineCol)
        self.multiText.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.updateLineCol)

    def updateLineCol(self, event):
        #lineNum = len(self.multiText.GetRange( 0, self.multiText.GetInsertionPoint() ).split("\n"))
        l,c = self.multiText.PositionToXY(self.multiText.GetInsertionPoint())

        stat = "col=%s, row=%s" % (l,c)

        self.StatusBar.SetStatusText(stat, number=0)

        event.Skip()

app = wx.App(False)
frame = TextFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```